# React Native Expo (Image Picker) is not displaying the Images

Tags: image, expo, display, imagepicker

Please help me out with this problem.
I can able to pick the image from my Local storage. In the Console also it is showing, But I cannot able to display it on the screen.
Here is my code.

```
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
    ActivityIndicator,
    Button,
    FlatList,
    Image,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    useWindowDimensions,
    View
} from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaProvider, SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

export default function App() {
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    const pickImages = async () => {
        // No permissions request is necessary for launching the image library
        setIsLoading(true);
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
            // allowsEditing: true,
            allowsMultipleSelection: true,
            selectionLimit: 10,
            aspect: [4, 3],
            quality: 1,
        });
        setIsLoading(false);
        console.log(result);
        if (!result.canceled) {
            setImages(result.uri ? [result.uri] : result.selected);
        }
    };

    return (
        <>

            <FlatList
                data={images}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <Image
                        source={{ uri: item.uri }}
                        style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
                    />
                )}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.uri}
                contentContainerStyle={{ marginVertical: 50, paddingBottom: 50 }}
                ListHeaderComponent={
                    isLoading ? (
                        <View>
                            <Text
                                style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: "bold", textAlign: "center" }}
                            >
                                Loading...
                            </Text>
                            <ActivityIndicator size={"large"} />
                        </View>
                    ) : (
                        <Button title="Pick images" onPress={pickImages} />
                    )
                }
            />
        </>
    );
}
```

I can able to pick the image from my Local storage. In Console also it is showing, But i cannot able to display it in screen.
Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're already passing the uri into the array. by doing [result.uri] and then in the image you're doing it again item.uri. trying just doing the item.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).